# How to get kernel source corresponding with the kernel installed by rpi-update

Tags: kernel

After an upgrade using [rpi-update](https://github.com/Hexxeh/rpi-update) the kernel could be upgraded. The script download the kernel from an other gihub repository [rpi-firmware](https://github.com/Hexxeh/rpi-firmware).

Till now, in order to get the kernel source, I download the last kernel source from git://github.com/raspberrypi/linux.git as it is explained in http://elinux.org/RPi_Kernel_Compilation. But the kernel source could be more recent than the one provided by rpi-update.

How to get the kernel source corresponding to the one installed by rpi-update ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I found rpi-source that do the job https://github.com/notro/rpi-source/wiki.